# Heroku S3 missing credentials in config, if using AWS_CONFIG_FILE, set AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG=1',

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, amazon-s3

I am facing a problem with uploading an image to heroku via S3. I don't have it locally but when I am in heroku I have this problem. I suspect that thhe credeantials are wrong but it works in localhost. Is there something missing or should I add some code

```
2020-06-17T16:26:58.525066+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 169.254.169.254:80
2020-06-17T16:26:58.525075+00:00 app[web.1]: at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1141:16) {
2020-06-17T16:26:58.525076+00:00 app[web.1]: message: 'Missing credentials in config, if using AWS_CONFIG_FILE, set AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG=1',
2020-06-17T16:26:58.525077+00:00 app[web.1]: errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
2020-06-17T16:26:58.525077+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 'CredentialsError',
2020-06-17T16:26:58.525078+00:00 app[web.1]: syscall: 'connect',
2020-06-17T16:26:58.525078+00:00 app[web.1]: address: '169.254.169.254',
2020-06-17T16:26:58.525079+00:00 app[web.1]: port: 80,
2020-06-17T16:26:58.525079+00:00 app[web.1]: time: 2020-06-17T16:26:58.517Z,
2020-06-17T16:26:58.525080+00:00 app[web.1]: originalError: {
2020-06-17T16:26:58.525081+00:00 app[web.1]: message: 'Could not load credentials from any providers',
```

This my code. It works fine locally but not in heroku

```
const aws = require('aws-sdk');
const fs = require('fs');

aws.config.update({
  secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_KEY,
  accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY,
  region: process.env.AWS_REGION
});


var s3 = new aws.S3({
  secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_KEY,
  accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY,
  region: process.env.AWS_REGION
});

async function addFile(fullpath = String,key = String) {

  const fileContent = fs.readFileSync(fullpath);

  var params = {
    Bucket: 'bucketeer-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    Key: fullpath,
    Body: fileContent

  };

  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    s3.putObject(params, function (err, data) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err, err.stack);
        reject(err);
      } // error
      else {
        console.log("added");
        resolve(data);
      }              // deleted
    });
  });


}

module.exports.addFile = addFile;
```

please help me with this stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably right that the credentials are missing. If you're accessing environment variables via `process.env` in code that you are running locally, then you will have to define them for the app instance that is running in Heroku as well.

On Heroku, they're called "Config Vars", and you can manage them either via the Heroku CLI or through the Dashboard GUI. Here's where you would find it in the GUI, but [Heroku's documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars) is also worth checking out.

[image: Heroku Config Vars]

Comment: Thanks for your rely. Icheck in the dashboard Ifound the same config as I have locally. BUCKETEER_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID // BUCKETEER_AWS_REGION // BUCKETEER_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY // BUCKETEER_BUCKET_NAME

Comment: Whatever you define in those Config Vars will be the values injected into `process.env`, so if your code is depending on `process.env.AWS_SECRET_KEY` then in Heroku you should have the exact same Config Var. The runtime has no idea what BUCKETEER_ is, so your credentials resolve to `undefined`

Comment: you mean that if I have in the config var BUCKETEER_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, then it should be the same in the code process.env.BUCKETEER_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY

Comment: Yep, that's correct. `process.env` is just a plain object, there's no magic in it. When you're running a process on Heroku, the values for that object come from the Config Vars, so you need to make sure that all of your keys match.

https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/process.html#process_process_env

Comment: I'm uploading the new code now and will give you reply then. but why in locally I have in my code process.env.AWS_SECRET_KEY and in the .env file BUCKETEER_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY and it works

Answer (score 1):

Finally solved the issue for aws in heroku.

You need to add your aws credential to "config Vars" by going to heroku app settings.

For example:-
[image]

```
aws_access_key_id=<add aws_access_key_id here>
aws_secret_access_key=<add aws_secret_access_key here>
aws_session_token=<add aws_session_token here>
```

(note:- here i am using sso hence i have aws session token if not using sso you might not have it)
finally then add:-

```
AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG=1     <- this is super important
```

This basically indicates heroku to look for aws config file
hence in your root directory or in your nodejs app where package.json node_modules etc are present create a folder ".aws"
inside this ".aws" folder create or add "config" file
containing

```
[default]
region = us-east-1
output = json
```

You can also skip adding aws credential in config vars of heroku and just keep this credential inside this config file i have not tested it yet.

I just kept aws credential at both places in inside config file as well as inside heroku config vars
lol was getting tired of solving errors.

Don't know which one it's picking up but its working i bet it's picking credentials from heroku config vars
as i am using:

```
AWS.config.update({
  region: "us-east-1",
  aws_access_key_id: process.env.aws_access_key_id,
  aws_secret_access_key: process.env.aws_secret_access_key,
  aws_session_token:process.env.aws_session_token
});
```

Hence logically it should update the credential taken from config file.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error because I'd forgotten to set the rails master key on heroku.

To do so, simply copy/paste the master key from `config/master.key` and set it like so:

```
heroku config:set RAILS_MASTER_KEY=c9102a13496fdc09430445a6602e3j85
```